# How to center in specific section of a pdf file created with RMarkdown a subtitle

Tags: pdf, text, header, r-markdown, center

I am trying to center the subtitle of a section for a pdf created with RMarkdown.

I am using the following code

````
---
title: "example"
author: "X"
date: "2023-09-23"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


## *Title*

### <h3 align="center" id="heading">*Title2*</h3>


```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

However I am getting this output

[image]

While the output I am looking for is:

```
Title
                          Title2 (at the center)
```

I do not know what I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this defining a latex macro that will center the subsubsection text.

```latex
\newcommand{\csubsubsection}[1]{
\subsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\centering\emph{#1}}{#1}}
}
```

and then use the raw latex command `\csubsubsection{subsection-title}` directly.

````
---
title: "example"
author: "X"
date: "2023-09-23"
output: pdf_document
---

\newcommand{\csubsubsection}[1]{
\subsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\centering\emph{#1}}{#1}}
}

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## *Title*

\csubsubsection{Model Applied (lm(y $\sim$ x))}

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: Thank you so much. Since I am not very into LaTex programming. Do you mind to briefly explain what each single commands you programmed does?

Comment: Anyway, on my hand I have the case where the title is more complex and contains a model syntax. Something like (Model applied: lm(x~y)). However, when I try to add this title, it turns me as error `Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.23 ... ~ y, random = ~ 1|A)`}}{section*.4}{}}`. What can I do in this case?

Comment: Okay, that error actually is coming from `\label{}` command. So I have simplified the answer. And see [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Commands#Defining_a_new_command) and please do google by the name of commands to know the details.